# React : Display relevant data next to each other in list item

Tags: reactjs

In my application, I am making multiple API call within one API call. My intention is to fetch title and release_date from 5 films API call simultaneously as shown in the code and display title and relevant release date next to each other (**e.g. The Empire Strikes - 1980-05-17**).

For that, I am using the map function to iterate over the title array and displaying in li but I am not getting the expected output. Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import charactersFile from "./data/characters.json"
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    title: [],
    release_date: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/1/`)
      .then(response => Promise.all([
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/2/`),
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/6/`),
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/3/`),
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/1/`),
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/7/`)
      ]))
      .then(result => result.map(values =>
        this.setState({
          title: [this.state.title, values.data.title],
          release_date: [this.state.release_date, values.data.release_date]
        })))
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.title)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.title.map(title => <li>{title}</li>)}
        </ul>
        {/* <h1>{this.state.title}</h1> */}
        <h2>{this.state.release_date}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

My Output :

[image]

Comment: so why dont you just put the data in the li?

Comment: I have already put

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: It's not clear what result you want your code to achieve. Everything is hard-coded.

Comment: something like this? [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/msf6rowc/)

Comment: you are trying to store data in two different arrays, when really it is related. Just store it in an object and map over those objects, rendering what you need in the `li` element.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Riya absolutely! happy to help :) let me know if you have more issues and or if something doesn't make sense! When you are able, if you wouldn't mind marking the answer as accepted so we can close this question out it would be much appreciated :D

Comment: Sure Appreciate it.

Comment: @Riya another example with hooks https://codesandbox.io/embed/sweet-jones-pjj3g

Comment: Thank you @WalidAmmar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the movie's data in two different arrays that you try to merge, just store the relevant data in an object and render each one together.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/1/`)
      .then(response => Promise.all([
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/2/`),
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/6/`),
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/3/`),
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/1/`),
        axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/7/`)
      ]))
      .then(result => result.map(values =>
        this.setState({
            movies: [
            ...this.state.movies,
            { title: values.data.title, release_date: values.data.release_date }
          ]
        })))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
            <li>
              <div className="title">{movie.title}</div>
              <span>-</span>
              <div>{movie.release_date}</div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```